# Swift generics and Any

Tags: swift, generics, decodable

I'm working with SignalR in swift and I'm trying to subscribe to different functions.

The documentation says (https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift)

> "It is worth noting that types for the handler parameters must be
> specified and must be compatible with the types of values sent by the
> server (e.g. if the server invokes the method with a string the
> parameter type of the handler cannot be Int). The number of handler
> parameters should match the number of arguments used to invoke the
> client-side method from the server side.

So the only thing I know about the parameters is that they conform to Decodable, so here is my generic function to handle them.

```
 private func subscribe<T:Decodable>(_ hubConnection: HubConnection, _ methodName: String, _ callback: @escaping ([T?])->()) {
        switch expectedParametersCount {
        case 2:
            hubConnection.on(method: methodName) { arg1, arg2 in
                        self.addAction({ callback([arg1, arg2])})
            }
            break
  }
```

This is where I call my subscribe function and run into troubles

```
private func hubConnSubscribe(_ hubConnection: HubConnection) {
        for kvPair in methodSubscriptions {
            subscribe(hubConnection, kvPair.key, kvPair.value)
        }
    }
```

But I run into problems when I try to store them: Here is my dictionary.

```
private var methodSubscriptions = [String : ([Any?])->()]()
```

this gives me the error

> Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'

and if I change it to

```
[String : ([Decodable?])->()]()
```

then I get

> Protocol 'Decodable' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself

so my question is what should my Dictionary look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a generic function and adding a generic value as needed, somethign like this.

```
 private func invoke<T: Encodable, U: Encodable>(_ methodName: String, _ callBack: Any?, _ callbackState: Any?, expectedArgs: Int,
                                                    _ arg1: T? = nil, _ arg2: U? = nil, _ arg3: T? = nil, _ arg4: T? = nil) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, you need the method subscribe() "kvPair.value" to receive something that conforms to "Decodable"
The way i see it you have two courses of action here.
Since Any does not conform to "Decodable" you can either:

1. make "methodSubscriptions" class get a generic type which conforms to "Decodable" like so:

   ```
   class SomeClass<T:Decodable> {

       private var methodSubscriptions = [String : ([T?])->()]()

   }
   ```
2. you can go to the easier approach making "methodSubscriptions" "Decodable" instead of "Any" like so:

   ```
   private var methodSubscriptions = [String : ([Decodable?])->()]()
   ```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I actually tried to changing it to [Decodable?] but when I do that I get the error "Protocol 'Decodable' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself" right where I tried capturing arg1, arg2 in my callback. I edited the question to elaborate more.

Comment: In that case i would suggest trying my first suggestion.
That way you will have a concrete type which conforms to "Decodable"